# ERROR: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python27 Selenium Webdriver with chromedriver and I'm getting this error on scripts that worked even few hours ago. I don't remember updating anything or changing anything so I'm confused how can unchanged code suddenly show errors.

This is the error:

> ERROR:service_manager.cc(158)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec
>   prevented service: content_plugin from binding interface:
>   memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser

Comment: I get this same error message with google-chrome-stable on ubuntu desktop when run from a terminal. There is no crash or problem however, so I would say that this is an error message that you can probably ignore.

Comment: I get the same error on browsers based on chromium 59.0.3071.104, for example vivaldi-snapshot_1.11.917.22 Whenever this error happens, video replay requiring chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra is extremely poor, with jittery video and unsynchronized voice and video. This makes those browsers unusable for watching netflix or amazon videos and it's necessary to use browsers built with chromium 57.*, which don't have this error.

Comment: I'm getting this, too, using `CefSharp` with a custom build of `CEF` (`CEF 3.3112.1650.g0488961` obtained from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html). Unfortunately for me, it hard crashes my application even with all the exception handling in the world.